# Is viewing anime girls in underwear permitted?

Tags: halal-haram, sex

I stopped watching porn alhumdilla and I don't watch hentai. But I sometimes see anime girls in her underwear. Is it haram?

Comment: Of course it is haram.

Comment: IMO, don't do it.

Comment: What makes you think you can see anime girls in underwear when you can't see normal girls in underwear?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is haram, so you should stop it, to protect your deen(religion) and honor.